# Manipulate item position in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in the fragments of my application, everything other thing is working but i don't have control over the positioning of items in the fragment as new contents is added to an item in the fragment i would want the item with the changes to move to the top so users can know changes occurred.

below is the code i already tried.

```
  @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query conversationQuery = mConvDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conv, ConvViewHolder> firebaseConvAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conv, ConvViewHolder>(
            Conv.class,
            R.layout.users_layout,
            ConvViewHolder.class,
            conversationQuery
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ConvViewHolder convViewHolder, final Conv conv, int i) {

            final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

            Query lastMessageQuery = mMessageDatabase.child(list_user_id).limitToLast(1);

            lastMessageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String data = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                    convViewHolder.setMessage(data, conv.isSeen());

                    //convViewHolder.setBadge(userBadge);
                    //mBadge.setNumber(mCount++);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


  mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                        String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                        convViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline, getActivity());

                    }

                    convViewHolder.setName(userName);
                    convViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                    convViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                            startActivity(chatIntent);

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };

    mConvList.setAdapter(firebaseConvAdapter);
    mConvList.scrollToPosition(-1);
    firebaseConvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sent code is imcomplete, However it's possible that you should add in the query an ordering by some field that tells you witch is the most recent record.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                    .setQuery(mFirebaseDatabaseHelper.fetchOnlineUsers()
                                    .orderByChild("update_at"),
                            User.class)
                    .build();

mAdapter = new FolderListAdapter(options, mListener, getContext());
```

Review these examples: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Comment: I actually have something like that. i just updated my question please check

Comment: It's some confused, but you could test using linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);